# Sites go down multiple times a day for a few minutes

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, cloudflare

Every morning I wake up to overnight Pingdom alerts that all of the sites on a particular server have gone down and come back up. They are usually down for 3-6 minutes. This will also happen in the middle of the workday at random times.

The most common errors I see are...

- "Reason: Socket timeout, unable to connect to server"
- "Reason: Invalid certificate"

But it always resolves itself after a few minutes.

My site runs through Cloudflare and my hunch is that Cloudflare is having trouble with my Certbot certificates. They are all in place and valid for another 83 days.

I just don't know where to start to diagnose the actual problem. There is nothing in any logs that I could find. Where would someone with more knowledge than me begin?

Comment: Look at logs on the hosts for reboots and daemon failures, other misbehavior. Contact cloudflare

Comment: Which logs would I look in for that? There aren't anything in the PHP error logs.

Comment: Do you think php logs are all logs host have? Do you have access to these hosts via ssh?

Comment: That is what I am saying. What logs would you look in? I have tons of log files, the PHP ones are just the ones that have have rolling across my screen all day.

Comment: Man, you should check all logs. It may depends how it configured. Grep time period when your host down. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#2-log-files-locations

Comment: If no reboots and apache not crashed it is networking issues on cloudflare or Pingdom side. What you monitor on Pingdom?

Comment: How exectly you detect situation "server have gone down and come back up". You see reboots in kernel.log? There is no ping? You cant connect via ssh? What exactly means "server down" in your case?

Comment: By server down, I mean I am getting emails from Pingdom that says all of the sites on my server were unreachable for a period of time. The only thing I have found that is new is this error that appears while the site is supposedly down.  "(70007)The timeout specified has expired"

Comment: You should know what exactly it check to decide server is down. Did you check kernel.log for reboots?

Comment: Take period  when server was "down"  last time and check what in kernel.log and apache logs around this period. Next time try ping, traceroute and ssh during downtime. Compare traceroute when server ok with when it down. Is it vps? Do you have some control panel with info about host?

Comment: Set up a second monitoring with something like hetrixtools to rule out it is not a pingdom issue. Then, check logs, apache errors? kernel? messages? How is your RAM? Are you swapping? OOM killer? Have you set up a cert on cloudflare site also? What cert is certbot issuing? CA or free letsencrypt???